# Get UIBarButtonItem From Detail View Controller

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

How do you get the UIBarButtonItem that pops out the main menu (when in portrait mode) of the DetailViewController when dealing with a master/detail split view controller? I want to change the title of that button and enable/disable it based on certain actions.

I tried:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.items...
```

But it doesn't get it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:  `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`